# How to do Onclick Javascript Session a part of variable from for loop and reposting through ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

First let me apologize for the confusing heading, i am not very sure on how to phrase it with my situation, it is a little complex.

The situation explained with an image.

1.) First i have a while loop of JSON data coming in from php( it contains multiple userid etc).
2.) Ajax picks up those data and place them into html with a button to each id. 
3.) When the button on click, it sends out that specific id to another php.

I have no idea how to get the data[i].userid and data[i].listingid from the ajax and send it out again. 
Thanks for your time

Image[image]

First php

```
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM list WHERE Listingid = '$Listingid' AND Status ='Bird'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
     $output[] = $row;
        }
        if (!empty($output)){

        echo json_encode( $output );}
        else{

            echo json_encode( [] );
        }
```

Javascript

```
 <script>

        function gup( name )
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return null;
  else
    return results[1];
}
        var frank_param1 = gup( 'Listingid' );
        $("#display12").append(frank_param1);
        console.log(frank_param1)

            $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "list.php",
   data: {"data":frank_param1},
                  dataType:'json',
            success: function(data){ 
                 for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) { 
                console.log(data)


                 var html1 = "<div class=two> Listingid : " + data[i].Listingid + "User id : " +  data[i].userid + "</div>" +
                     "<a id =newListing class=btn btn-success btn-lg1 type=button style=width:140px; href=#noteform  data-toggle =modal >"+"submit "+"</a>"
;




        $('#display12').append(html1); 
            }}







});




    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the data-variable in the success-callback should contain the data from PHP. You have JSON encoded the data in PHP, so you will have to [decode that JSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) if you want to print the actual data or something. If you just wanna forward it to some other script - you can make a new ajax-request in the success-callback and just stuff the encoded data in there without decoding it.

After decoding the JSON string, it should come out as the $output-array in JavaScript and you can just loop through it.

As for PHP, I don't exactly remember if $output[] = $row means pushing the rows in to the array, but regardless I would use array_push()-function to do it.

Comment: I tried to just push the JSON back through another .post or ajax post but i can't seem to send that because the data[i].user is inside a private variable.